# .Net 5 Cron job: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tasks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I have implemented a class who is responsible for making scheduled jobs using Cronos every 15 min
Always when I run the application, The first time the code is executed everything is working fine, but the next time I am having this error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tasks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

On the line : _context.SaveChanges();
Here is my code:

```
public class MyTasksCronJob : CronJobService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyTasksCronJob> _logger;
        private readonly Models.Hadeeth_Science_DBContext _context;
        private List<Models.Task> tasks = new List<Models.Task>();

        public MyTasksCronJob(IScheduleConfig<MyTasksCronJob> config, ILogger<MyTasksCronJob> logger, IServiceScopeFactory factory)
                : base(config.CronExpression, config.TimeZoneInfo)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Models.Hadeeth_Science_DBContext>();

        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("CronJob starts.");
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var phrases = _context.Phrases.FirstOrDefault();
            AddHolidays(phrases);
            _context.Tasks.AddRange(tasks);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            _logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss} CronJob Finished.");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("CronJob is stopping.");
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        private void AddHolidays(Models.Phrase phrases)
        {
            string title = "إرسال تنبيه بالعطلة";
            string days = "أيام";
            string day = "يوم واحد";
            string starting = "إبتداء من الموافق له";
            string duration = "لمدة";
            string when = "الموافق له";

            var holidays = _context.Holidays.Where(holiday => holiday.Date.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(3)).ToList();
            foreach (Models.Holiday holiday in holidays)
            {
                var task = new Models.Task();
                task.Type = "holiday";
                task.Title = title;
                if (holiday.NumberOfDays > 1)
                {
                    task.Body = phrases.HolidayOccasion + " " + holiday.Name + " " + phrases.HolidayAction + " " +
                        duration + " " + holiday.NumberOfDays + " " + days + " " + starting + " " + holiday.Date.Value.Date.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-LB")) + " " + phrases.HolidayEnding;
                }
                else
                {
                    task.Body = phrases.HolidayOccasion + " " + holiday.Name + " " + phrases.HolidayAction + " " +
                        duration + " " + day + " " + when + " " + holiday.Date.Value.Date.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-LB")) + " " + phrases.HolidayEnding;
                }
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your Task class has not defined which field is the IDENTITY column. Can you show the code of that class?

Comment: @Steve I am using Database first, and I am sure that the identity column is the primary key, and its auto increment